# Fatal signal 11 and weird error messages when taking picture with camera in Android

Tags: android, camera, crash, segmentation-fault, renderscript

I'm trying to take a picture with the camera, modify the image taken, and then display the modified image in the camera to the user after they clicked accept. Here's my code, with a comment above where I made code changes that created this error:

```
  private class TakePictureThread extends Thread {
    private Camera.PictureCallback pPictureCallback;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        pPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
                Camera.getCameraInfo(0, info);

                SurfaceView surfaceView = mCameraCaptureView.getSurfaceView();

                // TODO: scale this such that we don't need to scale the cropped image
                Bitmap unrotatedRawImage =
                        ImageUtils.decodeSampledBitmap(data,
                                surfaceView.getWidth(),
                                surfaceView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                Bitmap rawImage =
                        ImageHelper.rotate(unrotatedRawImage, info.orientation);
                unrotatedRawImage.recycle();

                mCroppedImage = cropRawCapturedImage(rawImage);
                rawImage.recycle();

                mCroppedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                        mCroppedImage,
                        ImageSize.CARD.getPixelWidth(),
                        ImageSize.CARD.getPixelHeight(),
                        false);

                mImagePreview.setImageBitmap(mCroppedImage);

                if (useBlurringAndGradient()) {
                    //new code
                    Bitmap blurredBitmap = ImageUtils.blurImage(mCroppedImage);
                    mImagePreview.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
                }

                handlePhotoTaken();
            }
        };

        mCameraCaptureView.getCamera().takePicture(null, null, pPictureCallback);
    }
}
```

And the blurImage method:

```
/**
 * Performs the max blur possible 20 times on the bitmap provided.
 */
static private Bitmap blurCardImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(MainApp.getInstance());

    Bitmap blurredBitmap =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Allocation allIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap);
        Allocation allOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, blurredBitmap);

        ScriptIntrinsicBlur blurScript = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        blurScript.setRadius(25.f);

        blurScript.setInput(allIn);
        blurScript.forEach(allOut);

        allOut.copyTo(blurredBitmap);

        bitmap = blurredBitmap;
    }

    rs.destroy();

    return bitmap;
}
```

Here's what the log looks like when this happens:

```
10-20 10:20:15.588: E/Camera(18230): Unknown message type 62273
10-20 10:20:15.588: E/Camera(18230): Unknown message type 62274
10-20 10:20:21.468: D/ProgressBar(18230): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
10-20 10:20:21.468: D/ProgressBar(18230): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
10-20 10:20:21.468: D/ProgressBar(18230): updateDrawableBounds: right = 228
10-20 10:20:21.468: D/ProgressBar(18230): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 228
10-20 10:20:22.408: D/dalvikvm(18230): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11182K, 19% free 55902K/68748K, paused 47ms, total 47ms
10-20 10:20:22.418: V/RenderScript(18230): 0x7b761008 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
10-20 10:20:22.428: V/RenderScript(18230): User-backed allocation failed stride requirement, falling back to separate allocation
10-20 10:20:22.498: A/libc(18230): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x7d9d7000 (code=1), thread 18869 (.myapp)
10-20 10:20:22.498: A/libc(18230): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x7d9d7000 (code=1), thread 18867 (.myapp)
10-20 10:20:22.498: A/libc(18230): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x7d9d7000 (code=1), thread 18868 (.myapp)
10-20 10:20:22.498: A/libc(18230): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x7d9d7000 (code=1), thread 18870 (.myapp)
```

Comment: enable verbose log level

Comment: @ben75 I updated the logs to the verbose level.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I can provide more details if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original answer wasn't producing the correct bitmap output I was expecting so I changed this part:

```
if (useBlurringAndGradient()) {
    Bitmap blurredBitmap = ImageUtils.blurImage(mCroppedImage);
    mImagePreview.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
}
```

to this:

```
if (useBlurringAndGradient()) {
    mImagePreview.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = mImagePreview.getDrawingCache();
    Bitmap blurredBitmap = ImageUtils.blurImage(bitmap);
    mImagePreview.setImageBitmap(blurredBitmap);
}
```

this has also fixed the crash I was getting and I no longer see the warnings in the logs. Does anyone know a reason that this fixes my problem?